# Timing issues in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

We want to keep track of the number of pages that a page is loaded so I've got this method to do so:

```
function track_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views';
    $count = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
    if($count == '') {
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '1' );
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, $count );
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering about is could this potentially miss views? If two users load the page at the exact same time or if there is high traffic, will the little of time to get the field, update it and reinsert it make this count not 100% accurate?

Ex: User 1 loads the page - page count is 4 while updating that var to 5, user two loads and gets page count 4 as well. updating it to 5 and reinserting it.

^is that how it would work? Or would the timing not really make too big of a difference?

We don't really care a whole lot about the number of times the page loads so we aren't planning on having a table filled with records of each load (insert a new record every load) but we would like to know if this would have a race issue against other page loads...and/or if it would create a conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that your code as written has a race condition.

What you would normally do in this case is atomically update the view count directly in the database:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    SET meta_value = meta_value + 1
    WHERE post_id = $postID AND meta_key = 'post_views';
```

and then if you actually need the value (such as to display it on the page), you would retrieve the new value from the database.

When done this way, the database will ensure that updates are atomic, and if you don't actually need the view count during the request, you make one less query (to fetch the data).

Comment: Strangely enough two randomly chosen, above average rated page hit counter plugins I just skimmed over have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

How important are stats to your organization?  Our PHB's want more than just page load data, so our tracker functions record each visit (time, user-agent, page visited, etc), and our reporting infrastructure just counts the visits matching certain criteria as each report demands.

So the DB insert isn't contentious ... the real issue is that you don't want to run the stats gathering routines on your webserver because they're DB-intense and might make your WWW apps choke.

Comment: Except that the issue is that the *update* is. When doing a get-modify-update cycle, there's always room for a race between two requests in different parts of that cycle.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct for the case where you're inserting other data into the database. Those inserts by themselves shouldn't be race-y (and you could just get a total after-the-fact by counting the records).

Comment: Exactly what we do ;-)